# KineticJS - Draw one layer to an offscreen canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

KineticJS takes hold of the canvases and controls their size and position.

I would like to have KineticJS render a layer to an offscreen 5000x2500 canvas, it seems a little complicated and "hacky" to get something like this done within KineticJS.

The only viable solution I can think of is to create a separate KineticJS Stage object and hide the container.

Any ideas, what the best method would be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use a KineticJS custom shape object as a viewport into an offscreen html5 canvas element**

The Kinetic.Shape object gives you access to many of the canvas and context properties/methods necessary to interface with a regular offscreen canvas element.